# Trouble using jQuery post inside non jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have the following script inside a HTML page:

```
<script>

function Test(){

alert("i got here");

 var username = document.registration_form.username.value;

 alert(username);

 $.post("checkname.php", { name:  username }, function(data) {

   alert("and here");

   alert(data);

   if (data = "0"){
       alert('That username is already in use, please choose another');
    return false;
   };
   if (data = "1") {
    return true;   
   };

});
};

</script>
```

I'm trying to get the function test to return true or false if a username is already in my database.

checkname.php contains the following:

```
<?

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['name'];


$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='".$myusername."'";


$result=mysql_query($sql);


$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count >= 1){
echo "0";
}
else {
echo "1";
}

?>
```

I've tried hardcoding a name and running the PHP and it works fine.

For some reason though when I run Test() the first 2 alerts come through fine, showing me the username enetered, but none of the subsequent alerts appear.

Oooo and jQuery has been added in the header like so:

```
<script src="create/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="create/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "jQuery function".

Comment: What would you like me to call the functions built into jQuery then?

Comment: You shouldn't put semicolons after the close braces of `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your return statements from the callback to $.post will *not* return from your Test() function. You should call Test with a callback function that deals with the data from the server, something like this:

```
function Test(username, callback) {
  $.post("checkname.php", {name: username}, callback);
}

Test(document.registration_form.username.value, function(data) {
  if(data == "0") {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
});
```

Brad is also correct about the comparison - you're currently assigning "0" to data. You should get the alerts though, I think, even with the other errors. Maybe you need the absolute path to the checkname.php script? E.g. "/checkname.php" (note the slash)?

Comment: Hmmm nope, still no alerts with the absolute path.

Comment: Do you have Firebug or Chrome/Safari Developer Tools? You might want to make sure that the ajax call comes through.

Comment: Hmmm my original code failed on the post. However with your changes its going through fine, its not returning the right value but i have enough to figure it out now....
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Off-hand, you should be using `==` for comparison in javascript. A single `=` is an assignment, `==` is a comparison. So having said that, `if (data = "0"){` would become `if (data == "0"){`.

Other than that, I don't see anything too fishy. You're allowed to use jQuery functions within "traditional" javascript function(){}'s.

Also, make sure you sanitize the input from the `$_POST['name']` using something like [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Thanks i've changed to double ='s now :). Still not showing the other alerts.... confusing me no end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the PHP script is returning a new line before or after it prints `0` or `1`.  So the string returned wouldn't equal `"0"` or `"1"`.

Try to change it to output JSON instead.

```
if($count >= 1){
  $ret = 0;
}
else{
  $ret = 1;
}
echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret));
```

And then change your `$.post` to:

```
$.post("checkname.php", { name:  username }, function(data) {
  alert("and here");
  alert(data);

  if(data.status = 0){
    alert('That username is already in use, please choose another');
  }
  if(data.status = 1) {
    alert('That username is not already in use');
  }
}, 'json');
```

NOTE: The `return false` and `return true` don't do anything.  You cannot return from an AJAX call.