# jQuery post inside another javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code like:

```
function duplicatecheck(value, colname) {
                var invoiceLineId = $('tr[editable="1"]').attr('id');

                var invoiceLine = {
                    InvoiceLineId: invoiceLineId,
                    InvoiceId: invoiceId,
                    ActivityId: value
                };
                $.post('/Invoice/InvoiceLineExistsForThisActivity/', invoiceLine, function (data) {
                    if(data == true) {
                        return[ false, "An invoice line already exists with this activity"]
                    }
                    else {
                        return[ true, ""];
                    }
                });
            }
```

The problem is that `duplicatecheck` is supposed to return a value. The value is inside the `post` callback function. So `duplicatecheck` runs and doesn't return anything because `post` is asynchronous and `duplicatecheck` finishes before the callback has even run.

Is there a way to make `duplicatecheck` wait until the callback has finished and return what the callback returns.

Am I going about this completely the wrong way and should be doing something else?

Comment: yes, you are going about this completely wrong. you should have your callback handling the response

Comment: You have to use a callback handler. This question has been answered before, take a look: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168739/trouble-using-jquery-post-inside-non-jquery-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you go the wrong way, JS is event driven, mostly
2. The $.POST has a sync/async flag, check [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you have the power to set async to false. That being said, preferably your web application should be structured in such a way that asynchronism is possible.

You should look into callbacks. If you run a function you know might take a while, provide it with a function that it will call when it's done. Useful links:

[Understanding callback functions in Javascript](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/)
[Getting a better understanding of callback functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483073/388916)